# Running two if statements in the same Sub

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have been trying to figure out how to run two If statements in one sub.   These If statements are completely different from each other.  They are not one action based off multiple conditions.   They are two actions affecting two button labels.

```
If x > 0 Then
Me.isResolved.backcolor = "5921504"
Me.isResolved.Caption =  X & " Notes need reviewed."
       If Y > 0 Then
       Me.unfinished.backcolor = "5921504"
       Me.unfinished.Caption = "You have " & Y & " unfinished orders"
       Else
       (Do this just changing captions and colors of me.unfinished) 
       End If
Else
(Do change color and caption of me.isResolved.)
End If
```

I tried Else if and some other ways,  but when I run a debug stop on any line if the first condition is met, it just ends the Sub.

Working on Access

Comment: If you want two separate if statements why are they nested?

Answer (score 0):

You could just have them follow each other:

```
Sub MySub()
    If x > 0 Then
        ' Code if x is positive
    Else
        ' Code if x is not positive
    End If

    If y > 0 Then
        ' Code if y is positive
    Else
        ' Code if y is not positive
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. I thought I tried that, but I separated it again and it seemed to work.  I tested it a few ways and all is good.   Thanks a bunch,  I might have fat fingered something.  I'm a mechanic doing this to try and help out our productivity.  I usually have 12 hours under my belt before I work on this data base.   Is there any limits to how many Ifs you can run in a sub?

Comment: @MKolberg nope, no such limit.